# Populate two database values from one dropdown select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a dropdown menu:

```
<%= f.collection_select :price, Print.all, :printprice, :sizetotal, {prompt: "Pick A Size & Medium"} %>
```

It currently populates the `:price` database column with the value `:printprice`, and shows the value `:sizetotal` in the actual dropdown selection.

I want to be able to populate two database columns, one of which is the `:price` column which is already working, but I also want to populate another column called `:size` with the value `:printsize`. I want to do this using the same dropdown select menu.

Something like:

```
<%= f.collection_select :price, :size, Print.all, :printprice, :printsize, :sizetotal, {prompt: "Pick A Size & Medium"} %>
```

But obviously the above doesnt work

Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm, you could just `collection_select :size` instead and use that to populate the price in the controller before saving it into the model?

Comment: It would clarify to have a simple code extract of your Print class, and maybe a sample HTML code the select you want. In any case, I'd suggest to use the ID of your print as value in the select, so on the controller side you can find the corresponding Print and extract whatever variables you need.
Or, you could use a function that serializes both your `price` and `size` in a single value, and deserialize it on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, here is the `ID` alternative. Basically you want to send only the ID of the print, and find again the whole object on the backend during the `#create` or `#update` actions

```
print_for_size_and_price = Print.find(params[:print_id_for_size_and_price])
```

So on the frontend I'd use something like this

```
select_tag(
  :print_id_for_size_and_price, 
  options_from_collection_for_select(Print.all, :id, :sizetotal)
)
```

And in the backend I'd do somewhere

```
my_instance.price = print_for_size_and_price.printprice
my_instance.size = print_for_size_and_price.sizetotal
```